# ReportViewer for MVC missing DLL dependancy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting, reportviewer, reportviewerformvc

After installing `ReportViewerForMVC` I get an error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: 
>   The type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' ...

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently **ReportViewerForMVC** uses Visual Studio 2012's **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms** DLL, version=11.0.0.0 as per the web.config:

```
<system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

1. If you do not have this DLL installed, then you will need to install [Visual Studio 2012 Report Viewer Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747).
2. If you do not have SQL Server 2012 installed, first you will be required to install [Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065), (direct links: [X86 version](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409), [X64 version](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409)).

Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms version 11 will be added to the GAC:

[image]

3. In Visual Studio add a reference to: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll